# Include Appendix of Apache 2.0 in LICENSE file?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-file

I want to use the [Apache 2.0 License](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache-2.0/) on one of my projects. Apache 2.0 recommends putting a boilerplate header in each code file right before module level documentation in it's Appendix section (bottom)

This is all well and good, but I can't find an answer on whether I should include the Appendix within the LICENSE file in the root of the project or take off the Appendix. Should I leave the license exactly as it appears on choosealicense.com?

For clarification, I'm talking about this section:

> APPENDIX: How to apply the Apache License to your work.
>
> To apply the Apache License to your work, attach the following
>     boilerplate notice, with the fields enclosed by brackets "{}"
>     replaced with your own identifying information. (Don't include
>     the brackets!)  The text should be enclosed in the appropriate
>     comment syntax for the file format. We also recommend that a
>     file or class name and description of purpose be included on the
>     same "printed page" as the copyright notice for easier
>     identification within third-party archives.
>
> Copyright {yyyy} {name of copyright owner}
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>     You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>     limitations under the License.

Comment: Source code and object code are sometimes referred to as the "before" and "after" versions of a compiled computer program. For script (noncompiled or interpreted) program languages, such as JavaScript, the terms source code and object code do not apply, since there is only one form of the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may freely omit the Appendix.

From the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0):

> 4. Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works thereof [...] provided that You meet the following conditions:
>
>    a) **You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License**; and...

And from section 1:

> "License" shall mean the terms and conditions for use, reproduction, and distribution as **defined by Sections 1 through 9 of this document**.

Since the Appendix is outside the stated scope of "Sections 1 through 9", the requirement in 4(a) that "You must give any other recipients... a copy of this License" does not include the Appendix.

Comment: Thanks, standby for another question regarding Apache 2.0.